# Why does adding a filter to 'the_title' break the server?

Tags: filters

I have this function that helps me nicely trim post titles:

```
namespace Helpers;
..
function _s_trim_post_title ( $length = null, $delimiter = null ) {
    $title          = get_the_title();
    $trimmed_title  = mb_strimwidth( $title, 
                                     0, 
                                     $length === null ? BIG_INT : $length, 
                                     '' // Won't use, bugs out.
                                    );
    $url            = esc_url( get_permalink() );

    if( strlen( $title ) == strlen( $trimmed_title ) ) {
        $delimiter = '';
    }

    $delimiter = $delimiter === null ? '' : (string)$delimiter;

    $output = '<h2 class="post-title"><a href="' . $url . '" rel="bookmark">' . $trimmed_title . $delimiter . '</a></h2>';

    return $output;
}
```

I call it, on `content.php` as follows:

```
echo Helpers\_s_trim_post_title(24, '...');
```

And I was thinking, how about of doing all that with a filter:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'Helpers\\_s_trim_post_title', 24, '...');
```

And now, on my `content.php`, I'd replace all that stuff with the simple:

`the_title()`

Unfortunately, this breaks the whole server and sends it into a continuous loop.

Why?

Comment: see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/ - your code uses `get_the_title()` within the filter, which in turn also uses the same filter....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct code snippet. Hope it'll work for you.

**Helper function**

```
namespace Helpers;
..
function _s_trim_content( $content = '', $length = null, $delimiter = null ) {
    $trimmed_content = mb_strimwidth( $content, 
        0, 
        is_null( $length ) ? BIG_INT : $length, 
        '' // Won't use, bugs out.
    );

    if ( mb_strlen( $content ) === mb_strlen( $trimmed_content ) || is_null( $delimiter ) ) {
        $delimiter = '';
    }

    return $trimmed_content . $delimiter;
}
```

**`the_title` filter**

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'post' === get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        return \Helpers\_s_trim_content( $title, 24, '...' );
    }
    return $title;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Obi! Thing is, reading about actions, this has a big problem:

How do I un-filter it? This is an anonymous function that's not called in any way.

Comment: You have to create named function to make it removable. `add_filter( 'the_title', 'op_trim_the_title', 10, 2 ); function op_trim_the_title( $title, $post_id ) { ... }` . To remove `remove_filter( 'the_title', 'op_trim_the_title', 10 );`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, please try to understand how filter hooks work inside WordPress. These two functions will help you in this case [`apply_fitlers()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) and [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)

Then please check how [`the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) filter hook works and what it does and how it does.

`the_title` filter hook is used in lots of places. It's been used in front-end as well as backend and it only works with the title. But you added heading `h2` tag and anchor `a` tag with it. You can use [`is_admin()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) conditional function to apply the filter only on front-end. So make sure your `the_title` filter callback only works with title and does not return any markup.

Your `the_title` filter hook callback `Helpers\_s_trim_post_title()` does not work with the arguments that it gets from the filter hook. And you called `get_the_title()` template tag inside `the_title` which became recursive call, an infinite loop! That's why your system isn't working as expected.

Comment: I've just started to dwelve into hooks / filters, this is of great help and I'm somewhat understanding how and where they should go. Would you please be able to provide some code as a fix? This could help me understand exactly where the pain points are and help me have the codex make even more sense with a practical exercise.

Comment: @JonathanGuerin Added another answer please check.